# How to generate new managed bean programmatically in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

*This example is just a dummy example to show the problem I'm having so don't get too caught up in alternate ways to solve the concrete problem in here. My question is more about understanding the proper technique to solve a type of problem in Spring*

Say I have a managed bean `Info`

```
@Component
public class Info {
  private final String activeProfile;
  private final Instant timestamp;

  public Info(@Value("${spring.profiles.active}") String activeProfile) {
    this.activeProfile = activeProfile;
    this.timestamp = Instant.now();
  }
}
```

The key here is that the bean needs something injected by Spring (the active profile in my example) and something that changes every time the bean is created (the timestamp in my example). Because of the latter, I can't use a `Singleton` scope. What is the proper way to get ahold of new instances of such a bean?

What I currently have is, the bean is *not* managed (no `@Component`, no `@Value`) and I have a managed service (a Controller) that invokes the constructor of a regular `Info` POJO explicitly. Something like

```
@RestController
public class InfoRestController { 
  @GetMapping
  public Info getInfo(@Value("${spring.profiles.active}") String activeProfile) {
    return new Info(activeProfile);
  } 
}
```

The problem with this solution is that it leaks the knowledge of the active profile to the controller just to pass it to the constructor of `Info`, when conceptually, the controller should not know about constructing the Info bean. That's one of the points of dependency injection

I have thought of some potential solutions:

- Have a reference to an `InfoFactory` [FactoryBean](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-factorybean) in the controller and then `return factory.getObject();`. But do I really need to create a new class for such a simple case?
- Have a `@Bean` factory method that constructs the managed bean. This still has the problem that the method is instantiating the `Info` POJO explicitly, so it itself needs to have the Spring injection done to it. Also, this is complete boilerplate.

The construction of the `Info` bean is so trivial that I imagine there is a simpler way to accomplish this in Spring. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing piece of the puzzle was `javax.inject.Provider`. I didn't know about it but it had exactly the interface that I was looking for. The final solution was to indeed let Spring manage the bean (`Info`) and use a `Provider` in the rest controller. This is the bean, almost exactly like in the OP

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class Info {
  private final String activeProfile;
  private final Instant timestamp;

  public Info(@Value("${spring.profiles.active}") String activeProfile) {
    this.activeProfile = activeProfile;
    this.timestamp = Instant.now();
  }
}
```

The bean has the Prototype scope as suggested by ruhul. I had tried that before but without the `Provider` I was still stuck. This is how to return it in the controller

```
@RestController
public class InfoRestController { 
  @Autowire
  private Provider<Info> infoProvider;

  @GetMapping
  public Info getInfo() {
    return infoProvider.get();
  } 
}
```

For the sake of completeness, I found another, uglier way of doing it by injecting the spring `ApplicationContext` and then using `context.getBean("info")` but the dependency on the spring context and the string name were a smell. The solution with `Provider` is much more focused

Comment: So every time you call `Provider::get` you get a new instance of prototype bean from the context? This is really good, did not know about `Provider`.

Comment: Yes. it integrates with the spring context. i found about it in some random SO comment

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need a managed new object when a request came. To achieve this you could mark your Bean with `@Scope("prototype")` that will solve your problem.

> A bean with prototype scope will return a different instance every time it is requested from the container.

To know more, how prototype works have a look at this page:

1. [Spring - Prototype scope example using @Scope annotation](https://www.boraji.com/spring-prototype-scope-example-using-scope-annotation)
2. [3. Prototype Scope](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes)

Comment: where would i put that annotation? in your examples it is always as part of a factory method, which i'm hoping to avoid (my second potential option in the list). Or you mean in the RestController `getInfo` method? can you provide an example of what you mean

Comment: also, who would instantiate the bean? i.e, how would the controller get a hold of the prototype-scoped bean to return it?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what is the changing thing. You could either use `protoype` scope as shown in ruhul's answer. However the problem here would be that the prototype instance would be injected only once when the `InfoRestController` bean is created.

You could try using [`request`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-request) scope - when you autowire a bean with such scope a new instance is created for each HTTP request :

```
@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Info {
    private final String activeProfile;
    private final Instant timestamp;

    public Info(@Value("${spring.profiles.active}") String activeProfile) {
        this.activeProfile = activeProfile;
        this.timestamp = Instant.now();
    }
}
```

This will make sure that a new instance of `Info` is created for each request :

```
@RestController
public class InfoRestController {

    private Info info;

    @Autowired
    public InfoRestController(Info info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Info get() {
        return info;
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind that `Info` instance injected into `InfoRestController` will be proxied so in this example you will be returning a proxy instance with some additional fields. To overcome this we could just make a copy of values from injected bean :

```
@RestController
public class InfoRestController {

    private Info info;

    @Autowired
    public InfoRestController(Info info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Info get() {
        return Info.of(info.getActiveProfile(), info.getTimestamp()); // create a copy
    }
}

@Component
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Info {

    private final String activeProfile;
    private final Instant timestamp;

    @Autowired // this constructor should be used by spring
    public Info(@Value("${spring.profiles.active}") String activeProfile) {
        this.activeProfile = activeProfile;
        this.timestamp = Instant.now();
    }

    private Info(String activeProfile, Instant timestamp) { // private constructor
        this.activeProfile = activeProfile;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public static Info of(String activeProfile, Instant instant) { //static factory method
        return new Info(activeProfile, instant);
    }

    // getters
}
```

Comment: i went down this route but the extra data in the pojo was annoying and ugly to remove. In any case, this works too. thank you